# Query and exclude in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the `match_phrase_prefix` query with an exclude query, so that it matches all terms except for the terms to be exclude. I have it figured out in a basic URI query, but not the regular JSON query. How do I convert this URI into a JSON type query?

```
"http://127.0.0.1:9200/topics/_search?q=name:"
                        + QUERY + "* AND !name=" + CURRENT_TAGS
```

Where `CURRENT_TAGS` is a list of tags not to match with.

This is what I have so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "name": "a"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "name": [
            "apple"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I do this `apple` is still included in the results. How do I exclude `apple`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you can use `must_not`, which is part of [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to exclude the documents which you don't want, below is working example on your sample.

**Index mapping**

```
{
 
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
  }
}
}
```

Index sample docs as `apple` and `amazon` worlds biggest companies which matches your search criteria :)

**Search query to exclude `apple`**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "name": "a"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "name": "apple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search results**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "matchprase",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "amazon"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I could suggest a small improvement by using the must_not into a filter. It will improve elastic cache capabilities, and then performances

Comment: oh thank you I did not know that. My query will be more simple. Thanks Opster